# Custom spot welder design for very small scale

Tags: capacitor, switching, discharge

This is an R&D project to test feasibility.
I need to try and weld a fine tungsten wire (50 micron) to a small piece of copper. 
The obvious solution (to me) is to place the wire on the copper and compress both side with an insulator, then feed in a current pulse.

If it works, local melting/bonding would take place.
The bulk of copper, being much more massive than the wire, could sink a lot of heat. The tungsten wire - well, it melts at over 3000degC so I am assuming most of the local melting happens at the copper interface.

So, the electronics question.
Given a capacitor, how do I discharge a massive current in a very short time? A mechanical switch would weld or be destroyed and I am not sure a MOSFET would do the job. I am assuming a ballpark energy of 10J to 100J

Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: You obviously can't run the current *along* the tungsten wire (lengthwise) -- the part not in contact with the copper will melt long before anything happens at the tungsten-copper interface. How are incandescent bulbs constructed? Don't they fold the other wire around the filament and then spot weld across the resulting sandwich?

Comment: The trouble I see is that tungsten electrodes are used for spot welding copper to copper so it might be problematic because a weld is a weld only if both parties melt and join (well that's what they told me at school a million years ago).

Comment: @DaveTweed That may not be a problem as long as the tungsten stays under 3000 degC

Comment: @Andyaka But do both parties have to melt? Or can the copper infuse or bond with the surface of the tungsten? This is why it is R&D

Comment: Both parties have to melt, or it is a solder and not a weld, by definition.

Comment: @ScottSeidman As long as the join is electrically conductive and mechanically strong, I don't mind what it is called

Comment: Is there any reason that a clamped (i.e., with a screw) or crimped connection is not a viable approach?

Comment: Current is rarely delivered via a wire to weld it to a more massive surface.  The wire will melt.  Look up how thermocouple junctions are made with capacitor discharge systems and you will see that they are fused with an arc discharge.  Spot welding systems that I have seen all have conductive (water cooled) copper or copper/tungsten electrodes made to minimise wear but still deliver the welding current (high) to create the melt pool.

Comment: @DaveTweed Mainly because it is going to be load bearing. It's not just an electrical contact. We are going to hang a weight from the wire in a very tiny space

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can you give some idea of the order of magnitude of the dimensions, forces and other constraints you're working under?

Comment: @DaveTweed Maximum force will be between 100g and 1kg. The piece of copper to which it will be bonded is around 5mm x 10mm

Answer (score 3):

I have slightly grave doubts about the welding to copper bit (what are the electrodes going to be made out of so they don't weld to the wire...), but on the electronics question, there was a spot welding project in the magazine **Digital Machinist**. It used a car battery and MOSFET or paralleled MOSFETs to control the current. I think the first of the multi-part installments was in [Spring 2017](http://www.digitalmachinist.net/coming-soon/spring-2017-issue).

Traditionally spot welders switch the primary of a step-down transformer, either to control mains power into it or to discharge a capacitor bank into the primary. Thyristors (or before that, a small thyratron) are used. The switched current is less by the ratio of the transformer, so a modest primary current can control many kA at the electrodes. In the case of the mains power, you can control the voltage with a variac and switch some number of cycles. In the case of the capacitor discharge, you have the capacitor voltage to play with, and potentially you can switch the discharge off if you use a suitable semiconductor (ie. not a thyristor).

Rather than fiddling around on your own, however, I would suggest talking to the engineers at a first class manufacturer of high-end precision spot welders and seeing what they have to say. No doubt they've run into something like your application and can advise you, maybe even do some test welds if you are planning on buying their product. Precision spot welding of relatively exotic metals is not uncommon in the manufacturing of instruments.

Comment: One of the electrodes will be the copper itself. The other is going to have to be the tungsten wire and hopefully we get a join where the two are in compression via alumina blocks